# FIG how to install the FIG program

Tags: html, terminal, fig

Is it possible to install FIG on Windows?

how to install the FIG program. I know there's one for macOS, but I can't find one for windows. Maybe there is an alternative to this ? I really want to see autocompletions in the terminal